# Flutter Retrofit, using different base urls for development and deployment

Tags: flutter, retrofit, cd

I use retrofit to generate my api client in dart/flutter.

I have a version of the server on my local machine and a version hosted.

I want to use the local machine as the base url during development and testing, and a different base url when I build for deploy.

I don’t want to manually change it every time.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you use this plugin you can [retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit)

`Api(dio, baseUrl: RunConfig().apiBaseUrl)`

and you can also use [flavor](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors) and create 2 different main.dart

Comment: Looks promising, let me try and see